# Logic App Service Bus Connector takes minutes to complete message

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

Hi i have run into a problem with logic apps workflows.
Specifically the problem i have run into is when trying to complete an Azure service bus message after the workflow is done.

The whole workflow takes about between 1-5 seconds to complete, but as soon as I'm about to complete the message as the last step. that service bus connector can take up to 5 or even 8 minutes to complete. and by then the lock token has already expired.

I have tried to extend the lifespan of the token but the maximum time i can put is 5 minutes.

Also anyone know the reason for this delay?

it only happens to one of my workflows i haven't seen it in the others.

I tried to recreate the whole logic app even deleting it and recreating it from scratch but i still run into the problem...

Also sometimes it takes time to send the message to another queue.

[image]

Also by this screenshot the token shouldn't even have to be expired or lost.

[image]

So at the end i get these types of error messages:

> "message": "Failed to complete the message with the lock token '{GUID}'. The lock on the message has been lost.\r\nclientRequestId: {GUID}",
>
> "message": "No session available to complete the message with the
>   lock token '{GUID}'.\r\nclientRequestId: {GUID}",
>
> "message": "This messaging entity has already been closed, aborted,
>   or disposed.\r\nclientRequestId: {GUID}",
>
> "message": "BadRequest. Http request failed: the timeout was reached."

Am i doing anything wrong? 
What could be the cause of this?

Comment: In the past I have used logic app with service without any problem. If you use the "When a message is received in a queue (auto-complete)" trigger, your message will be completed if the workflow is successful. Otherwise why are you trying to complete the message after you send it ?

Comment: The complete message action is to be used only when you have peeked-locked an *input* message, as explained here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/50022.how-to-peek-lock-a-message-from-service-bus-queue-using-azure-logic-apps.aspx. If you are sending a message to Service Bus, there is no need to complete or do anything else with that message.

Comment: You guys are both right about what you are saying, but the thing is i'm using peak lock because i have a fifo structure in my workflow throughout my integration. The messages have to come in a specific order. That's why i'm using a peak-lock.but i still don't understand why sometimes the messages get through with no problem in a matter of seconds and other times it can take them up to around 8 minutes.

Comment: @John why are you completing the message after sending it ? The consuming application should complete the message ?

Comment: The reason is the api that consumes the message is a service so we have to take account for that. i.e work around not changing the service they have baught.

Comment: @John, check if you have partitioning enabled, if not enable it and see if it helps. with partitioning enabled, there will be multiple message brokers handling the messages as they arrive, so it would distribute the load among the partitions, hopefully resulting in some performance improvements

Comment: I'll definetly look into that. Thanks @PranshuGupta :)

Comment: Ok, so 've looked into it, partitioning is actually enabled @PranshuGupta.